# How can I brew a stronger cocoa drink?

Tags: cocoa

I read [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14103/can-you-make-chocolate-from-coffee-beans-or-coffee-from-cacao-beans/14104#14104) and [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56629/is-there-a-drink-thats-analogous-to-coffee-but-made-with-cocoa-beans/56638#56638) that cocoa powder could be "brewed" like coffee for a cocoa-flavored coffee-like hot drink.  Today I bought some cocoa powder and a reusable coffee filter cup, and I tried it out myself with a single-cup coffee maker.  I got a drink that seems quite promising, but it brewed very weak and watery.  How can I get a stronger cocoa powder brew?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't brew cocoa like coffee, with filtering. You drink the cocoa powder together with the liquid.

Making breed cocoa is super easy, just take a small pot, mix gradually the cocoa powder with cold water, them let it cook up like Turkish coffee. Then drink without any sieving or filtering. You can add sugar if you like.

If it is still watery, add more cocoa powder next time.

Comment: I found that there is some sediment left when using this method, but transferring from one glass to another gets rid of most of it.

Comment: Sure there is sediment, most people drink it. It is the same stuff you eat in a chocolate bar.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough A friend of ours sent us a bag of cocoa designed specifically for just that kind of thing. I was surprised at how good it was, and supposedly the way cocoa was consumed in Central and South America before it was ground into power and sweetened to give us Chocolate.

https://criobru.com

I have no financial interest or know anyone in the company, I'm just a satisfied customer.

Comment: Your answer led me to [this bit of information](https://criobru.com/pages/faq): "Short answer is we don’t recommend [brewing in a Keurig machine]. Keurig machines have settings have a very quick extraction and cacao needs to brew a little slower. Long answer is that there are some customers that tinker and tinker and depending on the machine and their brewing method make it workable."  So your recommendation doesn't fix the problem but it did lead me to finding more information...

Comment: We got a "single-cup coffee maker" too. The French Press works well and we happily use it when we have a hankering' for some brewed cocoa. I didn't connect "single cup coffee maker" with "Keurig." I don't drink coffee so I have no opinion on them but my wife turns her nose up at such machines. To each his/her own.